# Comparar una cadena con otra

Tags: java, string

Les pido ayuda en el siguiente problema que puede ser visto en la depuración de este programa donde estoy realizando una comparación con equals, las dos cadenas tienen el mismo contenido pero el resultado es false en la comparación, qué es lo que está mal planteado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues la verdad si que está bien raro. ¿Estás seguro que no entra? ¿Esa evaluación que se muestra de `cada.equals(nomb)` la hiciste justo con la ejecución detenida en ese punto? ¿Probaste (solo para testear) con `equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: El valor de `cada.equals(nomb)` que aparece abajo, ¿es de la iteración actual seguro? ¿No será de la anterior? ¿Si pones una línea debajo de `cada = ...` que sea algo como `boolean equals = cada.equals(nomb);` le da el valor `false`? Por último, ¿si `nomb` o `cada` tuviera caracteres especiales, aparecerían en la lista abajo? Por ejemplo `\0`, `\n`, `\r`

Comment: Muchas gracias por las pistas, sigo revisando, probé con equalsIgnoreCase y nada, sigue igual, si todas las evaluaciones son false, lo que estoy sospechando es que son valores escondidos que no despliega el string y hacer una depuración de su contenido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba originado en la construcción del String "cada", aunque el contenido parece el mismo, existía algún problema, pues estaba leida desde disco con RandomAccessFile.readline, y al particionar con split(caracter separador) el objeto String no era el mismo, por lo que daba diferencia, lo que hice fue

```
 `introducir el código aquí StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20);
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                char car = archi.readChar();
                if (car != ' ')
                    sb.append(car);
            }
            
            String cada = sb.toString();
```

con lo que se pudo solucionar el problema